# If the set $f^{-1}\{a\}$ is measurable for all $a$, then is $f$ a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory

What can be said about the measurability of an extended real valued function, defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the set $\{x:~f(x)=a\}$ is measurable for each extended real value $a$? I think that $f$ is measurable. But can't think of how to prove it. I am starting with some $a$. Then the set $\{x:~f(x)>a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:~f(x)=a+\frac{1}{n}\}$. Since each of the sets in the union is measurable so $\{x:~f(x)>a\}$ is measurable. Is the above argument correct? Kindly help.

Comment: This is wrong: $\{x:~f(x)>a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:~f(x)=a+\frac{1}{n}\}$

Comment: Thanks. Even I was unsure about it.

Comment: But there are other duplicates too. I recall giving answers on this question with previous accounts.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Martin R  your argument is not correct.

I will assume that all uncountable subsets of $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

If $E$ is a non-measurable set then $E$ and $E^{c}$ are uncountable subsets of $\mathbb R$. Let $g: E \to [0,1]$ and $h: E^{c} \to [2,3]$ be bijections and $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x \in E$ and $f(x)=h(x)$ for $x \in E^{c}$. Then $f^{-1}(a)$ has at most two points for all $a$ but $f^{-1}([0,1])=E$ is not measurable.

Comment: Ok. That means the assertion is not true. Thanks for the counter example.